# Has Unix been used by accountants and other non-programmers at AT&T in the 70s and 80s?

Tags: history, unix-philosophy

In the short documentary, *Ken Thompson and Dennis Ritchie Explain UNIX (Bell Labs)* it is [mentioned](http://youtu.be/JoVQTPbD6UY?t=34s), that Unix is not only an OS, but also

> a system around which a community could form.

I find this statement remarkable; but did this community include for example accountants and other non-technical people? If so, could they use the shell and the tools of their peers to glue together solutions for their actual problems? Or did they need to wait, until a colleague wrote a nice TUI for them, so they did not have to deal with an unfamiliar environment like the shell?

Are there resources about the (historical) usage of Unix (on the shell level) by less technical people?

Comment: The entire video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvDZLjaCJuw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer from a [Program design in the UNIX environment](http://harmful.cat-v.org/cat-v/unix_prog_design.pdf):

> (Often a single property of the system will be taken as an asset or as a fault by different audiences; **our audience is programmers, because the UNIX environment is designed fundamentally for programming.**)